# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Category series name is null

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to display a simple report with a textfield : "hello world".

The problem is i'm getting an error message category series name is null and i don't know why. Does anybody have a clue?

The server log

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Category series name is null.
at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillCategoryDataset.customIncrement(JRFillCategoryDataset.java:142)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementDataset.increment(JRFillElementDataset.java:191)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.calculateVariables(JRCalculator.java:183)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:742)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:262)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:122)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:551)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:411)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:732)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:216)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

printreport method:

```
public void printReport() throws JRException, IOException, NamingException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
    File jasper = new File("/some/path/to/report.jasper");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper.getPath(),new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());        
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, someOutputStream);
}
```

jrxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1119a425-bbc5-4d11-93a1-ab32daa4ccbc">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="254" y="22" width="100" height="20" uuid="a59aa154-093e-4330-8be7-515e56d76412"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["HELLO WORLD"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the input data.

You are using the method:

```
fillReport(JasperReport jasperReport, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> parameters, JRDataSource dataSource)
```

However you have neither parameters nor a datasource specified.

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper.getPath(),new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
```

I think your report contains more than just a label. This error appears when you try to show a chart in a report which has no data or a similar structure.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, I just tried with another report containing a chart and set the datasource, now the pdf file download starts but i get 'Connection to the server exceeded the maximum number of tries'

Comment: You misunderstood. The error you described typically indicates a chart. But you want only a label, so you should build your jrxml accordingly i.e. without any such charts. You can add them later with the query and parameters once you see you can actually get a report.

Comment: Check this http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/529984/blank-report-generated . Strip the jrxml example of any images or content you don't care about, compile and use it. You should be able to export something

Comment: i forgot to mention that i'm using the jasperreport plugin for netbeans, so i'm building my jrxm files using the designer, could it be a problem with the plugin ?

Comment: It shouldn't. Post the jrxml

Comment: i added the jrxml in my post

Comment: Update: i've tried 'public void generate()' in the link you gave me, now it's working with my report, it generates a pdf file that with the text i wrote, i added a chart that uses a sql query, and added the connection to JasperFillManager.fillReport, but i'm getting an empty chart in my pdf file

Comment: Good job. Check the sql query you run for the chart. Run it on the database, see the result set it returns. See if it's structured properly for the chart and so on. The rest is beyond the scope of this question. Feel free to ask another question if you encounter any more difficulties. Remember the stack overflow question rules, it has to be specific and you have to show effort.

Comment: Thank you so much,  the problem was a typo in the mysql connection link, everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, after hour comparing codes i found value has changed for blank. try look this

```
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="MYdataAdapter"/>
```